# JAX-RS @PathParam How to pass dots

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm writting REST API and I have path like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/vehicle/tab.parameters/common.tab.vehicle
```

And my question is how to pass dots in param. Thanks for all answers.

Edit:
I would like to avoid string conversion (dots to %2). I've tried something like this:

```
@Path("vehicle/{currentFrom:.+}/{selectedTab:.+}")
```

But then I have correct selectedTab but currentFrom is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class URLEncoder on the client side for this:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/Project/vehicle/" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("tab.parameters/common.tab.vehicle", "UTF-8")
```

On the server side you can then decode it again with the class URLDecoder.

Comment: "." char is not being encoded by this class. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Like with many special characters in URLs, you will have to [encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them. The code for dots is %2E, so your example would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/vehicle/tab%2Eparameters/common%2Etab%2Evehicle
```